# lvm sizes don't add upto the partition size

Tags: linux, partition, lvm, parted

If you see these are my two partitions `1 and 2`

[image]

Now if we look at the partition level

[image]

sda2 is total of 149.5G ie `root, swap, home of 50, 3.8, 25.7G each` but that still not adds upto total size of the partition. So my question is where is that `149.5 - (50 + 3.8 + 25.7)` i.e the 70G how can I retrieve this space and use it?

EDIT 1 : 
`vgs`
[image]

**EDIT 2 :** 
`pvs`

[image]

**EDIT 3 :** Ran `pvresize /dev/sda2` which gave pvs and vgs as

[image]

**EDIT 4  :** Ran `lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/vg_relcertlin2/lv_root` but df -hT and lsblk are showing different output
[image]

Comment: Add the output of `vgs` to your question. Copy and paste it instead of linking an image.

Comment: Please check the updated question, I am sorry I could not copy paste cuz I am connecting to the machine using hyper V and it does not allow to copy paste

Comment: Did you grow the partition and forgot `pvresize /dev/sda2`?

Comment: I didn't do pvresize ! what is it

Comment: Add the output of `pvs` as well. If you ssh into the machine, then you can copy and paste the output.

Comment: No its not ssh, just connect using the GUI by right clicking on it. Please check updated

Comment: Then set up ssh on it and use that to connect.

Comment: Again I cannot ssh, because for some reason I cannot access internet on this machine. And since its my on my company's cloud I am able to use it only through the hyper V

Answer (score 0):

Your physical volume isn't using all of the space in `/dev/sda2` and as a result, neither is your volume group.

To get the space:

```
pvresize /dev/sda2
```

That will extend the physical volume and volume group to use all of the space. Verify with:

```
pvs

vgs
```

Comment: I did that, after that how can I use the space because its still not showing on `lsblk`

Comment: please help me out with this, its very important

Comment: @PulkitBhatnagar It's not going to show in `lsblk` because you haven't added the space to any of your logical volumes. Look at `pvs` and `vgs` again to see the difference.

Comment: yes it changes, now ist showing on free as 70GB

Comment: But how do I add this to my sda 2 partition?

Comment: @PulkitBhatnagar It's already in the physical volume of `/dev/sda2`. To add it to your logical volumes, use the `lvextend` command. Read the man page and it'll show you what to do.

Comment: is it right ? `lvextend -l 100%FREE dev/sda2`

Comment: @PulkitBhatnagar Read the man page. The physical volume is already extended so there's no reason to do anything else to it and you have what you want. If you want to extend the logical volumes, then you need to run `lvextend` against the logical volumes with the amount of extra space that's needed, not the physical volume. If you really need help, have someone where you work walk you through it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the space, this resizes the amount of space that a LVM volume group can use on a partition and needs to be run if you resize its partition.:

```
pvresize /dev/sda2
```

we need to resize the logical volume

```
lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/vg_relcertlin2/lv_root
```

Finally we want to resize the actual underlying file system

```
resize2fs /dev/vg_relcertlin2/lv_root
```